# Queue Thread In Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, concurrency, java-me, threadpool

I've looked at the BB API(5.0) and I can't find any way of serially executing a batch of threads. I know BB has a limit on the number of threads it will launch, so I don't want to launch 7 if the user clicks through things fast enough but I cannot find anything like a thread pool.

Is there an easy fix for this or do I have to create a data structure?

Comment: why do you want multiple threads?  What about having the UI launch a single thread that does X, Y, Z?

Comment: Because each event is different. I want to launch them so the UI is not being blocked on waiting for things to be done.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you just want to execute a bunch of tasks on a single thread serially and order isn't important, you could create a [Timer](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/java/util/Timer.html) object (which has its own thread) then add each task to it as a [TimerTask](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/java/util/TimerTask.html).  If you schedule it with a delay of 0 or 1, it will essentially run that task as soon as possible.  And since a Timer only has a single thread, if you schedule multiple tasks concurrently, it will ensure that only one will run at a time.

Incidentally, I was talking to a RIM engineer at the BlackBerry Developer Conference this year and he said that as of OS 5.0 there are no longer limits to the number of threads -- so this is becoming less and less of a concern.

Comment: Even if the OS upped the limits threads are still an expensive resource on a constrained env like a mobile device.  It's always good practice to reduce the number of threads needed when possible.

Comment: Hello all, my applications requirement is it has to access network in every page. What I am doing is I am creating an inner class that extends Thread for every screen that performs requires network connectivity, Is this a correct approach? Help of any sort is appreciated.

A Y.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested Jeff Heaton's Thread Pool example on 4.5 and it works.  (http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30483&seqNum=1).